# How do I take a subvector of a vector in Cython?

Tags: cython

If I have a vector of a generic type (say `cdef vector[string] a = [b'a', b'b', b'c']`), how do I get a subvector from it?

`a[:2]` converts it to a Python list and incurs an overhead, while the standard C++ way (`cdef vector[string] b = {a.begin(), a.begin() + 2})`) gives me a Cython compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cython does not support the many convenient modern c++ syntax sugar, you have to use the interface exported in `vector.pxd` from Cython Includes folder:

```
cdef vector[string] a = [b'a', b'b', b'c']
cdef vector[string] b
b.assign(a.begin(), a.begin() + 2)
```